# What's wrong with my C character and line counting program?

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

I was reading Kernighan Ritchie and there's this Character counting program, so I tried implementing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char c;
int i;
c = getchar();
while (c != EOF)
    i= i + 1;
printf("%d",i);
}`
```

When I compile and run this code, after I enter some characters there's no output after that. No number is printed and I can't figure out why. The code looks fine. I also tried using scanf() but the same thing happened.

The next example was for counting lines in input and the same problem was there too.

Comment: Please be aware that C++ is not C.

Comment: if  c!=EOF "while" loop will be infinite

Comment: `int i = 0, c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    i = i + 1;`

Comment: Please do not wildly edit your question after people have posted answers. Now neither your question nor the answers make any sense at all.

Comment: @Lundin Noted and sorry.

Comment: How is `c` supposed to change inside the loop??

Comment: [`getchar`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code, when you're hitting

```
 i= i + 1;
```

the initial value of `i` is indeterminate. So, the whole program invokes  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to initialize `i`.

To elaborate, `i` being an automatic local variable, unless initialized explicitly, the content is indeterminate. Using an indeterminate value in this case will lead to UB.

That said, a `char` is not able to hold a value of `EOF`, change the type to `int`.

---

After that, you're wrong in the logic. `getchar()` is not a loop on it's own, you need to keep calling `getchar()` inside the `while` loop body to update the value of `c`, used in the condition check in `while`.

Comment: oops, yes I assigned 0 to i but that didn't solve the problem and neither did changing type of variable c to int. I have edited the question.

Comment: ... and [`getchar`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
```

Good. Not `main()` and not `void main()`. Keep it this way.

```
{
char c;
```

Bad. `getchar()` returns an **int**.

```
int i;
```

Bad. Not initialised, value is indeterminate. You are going to increment -7445219, or perhaps a kidney pie, who knows.

```
c = getchar();
```

Ok you have read a single character.

```
while (c != EOF)
```

But you cannot compare it to `EOF` because `EOF` doesn't fit in a `char`.

```
    i= i + 1;
```

Looks like you forgot to do something in the body of the loop. Something that is going to change `c` perhaps so that your loop has a chance to finish.

```
printf("%d",i);
```

It is recommended to add a newline to the last line of your output.

```
}
```

That's all folks.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add an inicialization for "i"

int i = 0;

Answer (score 0):

You missed the initialization:

int i = 0;